# При столкновении с триггером персонажа должно отталкивать. Как сделать не через AddForce?

Tags: unity3d

Игра - головоломка. Персонажу надо от одного острова добраться через воду до пляжа. Для этого нужно поставить надувные круги так, чтобы персонаж от них отпрыгивал и не упал в воду. у каждого круга свои способности. например обычно от круга персонаж отскакивает вперед от другого в бок от третьего еще какая то способность.
Как сделать плавное движение персонажа при входе в триггер? Я это сделал с помощью Addforce, но если персонаж заходит в круг который просто отталкивает вверх потом в круг который отталкивает в право а потом опять в круг который отталкивает вверх, то персонажа начинает мотать то влево, то вправо. Поэтому я думаю сделать движение через AnimationCurve или еще как - то, но еще не сообразил как это сделать. Заранее спасибо

[image]

Comment: Переформулируй свой вопрос, потому что в данном виде это не вопрос, а какой-то поток сознания. Отталкивание сделано через Addforce или velocity? Что значит движение через триггер? Где код движения?

Comment: Изменяй velocity, сделай множитель скорости и изменяй его в корутине в зависимости от значения кривой.

Comment: @KOTlK можно по подробнее

Comment: Объявляешь поле типа Vector2, в котором будет храниться множитель скорости по осям. При пересечении триггера, запускаешь корутину, которая будет рассчитывать этот множитель в зависимости от кривой. В FixedUpdate присваиваешь velocity компоненту rigidbody.